# Bad formatting on bottom row of reputation graph

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-graph

It looks like there are some issues with the reputation graph on the User Activity page. On [my profile on IPS](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/11811/scohe001), the left axis overlaps the graph itself:

[image]

This issue seems to be unique to my profile (possibly because of the difference in the number of digitis on the axis?). However, it looks like the "7.1k" is a few pixels too low. This looks like it happens on all graphs, even good ones:

[image]